# error code [1411]; Incorrect datetime value: '' for function str_to_date; nested exception is : Incorrect datetime value: '' for function str_to_date

Tags: sql, database, mysql-workbench

im getting above error when i run my web based application on live server. it was running fine till few days back when we had a server crash. Now after re installation we are getting above error.

However the same application is running without that error in my local system.

I even tried running below queries as suggested by peers but of no use.
Please help to resolve the issue.

```
SET SESSION sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
SET SESSION sql_mode = 'ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

SET SESSION sql_mode = '@old_sql_mode';
SET @old_sql_mode = @@sql_mode;
```

Query is :>

```
insert into at_ph_stockist_invoice(stockist_id, invoice_no, invoice_date, invoice_amt, invoice_disc_per, invoice_disc,taxable_amt,gst_amt,
    final_invoice_amt,invoice_status, pymnt_type, po_amt, po_id, po_num, po_dt,final_amt, added_by, added_on, added_ip, status_id, 
    pay_bill_date, amount_received, change_given, balance) 
    values(#{stockistId}, #{invoiceNumber},  DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(#{invoiceDate}, '%e-%b-%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d'), 
    #{invoiceAmmount}, #{discountPercentage}, #{discountAmmount},#{taxableAmt}, #{gstAmount}, #{finalInvoiceAmount},if(#{paymentType}='credit', 'pending', 'paid'), #{paymentType}, 
    #{poAmt}, #{poId}, #{poNumber}, DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(#{poDate}, '%e-%b-%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d'),#{finalAmount}, 
    #{addedBy}, now(), #{addedIp}, fn_getcodevalue_id('STS','Active'), DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(#{payBillDt}, '%e-%b-%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d'), 
    #{amountReceived}, #{chngGiven}, #{balance});
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Can you inspect the 3 parameters involved and figure out what they actually send to the insert script? As you can see below I tried to replicate but wasn't able to (this may be due to dbfiddle configuration)  - so I think more details may be needed. And: **please** edit your tags to indicate which dbms you use and also tell us which version - these details are really is important.

Answer (score 0):

The insert uses str_to_date in 3 places:

```
INSERT INTO at_ph_stockist_invoice (
    ...
    , invoice_date
    , ...
    , po_dt
    , ...
    , pay_bill_date
    , ...
    )
VALUES (
    ...
    , DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(#{invoiceDate}, '%e-%b-%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d')
    , ...
    , DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(#{poDate}, '%e-%b-%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d')
    , ...
    , DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(#{payBillDt}, '%e-%b-%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d')
    , ...
    )
```

I am unable to replicate this issue at dbfiddle using see [MySQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/5ebmZ14u) (or [MariaDb](https://dbfiddle.uk/LGTSd2WG))

```
SET SESSION sql_mode = 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES';
SET SESSION sql_mode = 'NO_ZERO_DATE';

select
  STR_TO_DATE('', '%e-%b-%Y') a
, DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('', '%e-%b-%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d') a1
, STR_TO_DATE(' ', '%e-%b-%Y') b
, DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(' ', '%e-%b-%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d') b1
, STR_TO_DATE(null, '%e-%b-%Y') c
, DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(null, '%e-%b-%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d') c1
```